Windows 11 - Network traffic cuts out (Both wired and Wifi)
I have a strange problem. The other day, my work laptop started acting up.
I as logged in to an rdp and the connection became very unstable.
As this happens as times, I didn't think much about it.
But as I didn't really recover I started to look into it.
I found out, that all network traffic will cut out after a few seconds. It will be down for a similar amount of time and then come back and so on.
I also tried pinging both my server and google, and a bunch of packages times out and the other have very high latency (2000-3000ms).
Running the same ping command from a different computer (both laptop on Wifi and workstation that is wired) yields about 15-20ms to google an no timed out packages.
Connecting to the rdp form an other computer or phone (on the same network) works just fine.
I've reset the stacks, flushed dns and all the regular stuff, but to no avail.
I'll go on to updating the drivers, but as the problem persist across multiple network interfaces I don't think it will make a difference.
Image of the Task manager showing network traffic stopping during an active rdp session

Anyone got any other ideas?
